# Wildcard * in a Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, scripting, sas

I would like to use the * wildcard to list all the sas program files in my Windows directory.  Thus I issue the command 
    **dir *.sas**
But when I do this the command will also list all sas datasets as well as catalogs because they have extensions .sas7bdat and .sas7bcat respectively. How do I restrict the dir command to only list the sas program files?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar quesiton here.  https://superuser.com/questions/825615/windows-wildcards-with-files-having-more-than-3-characters-extensions

The answer from that thread is that you cannot change the behavior.  There were two proposed solutions:

- Switch to using powershell instead of cmd.exe
- add a step to filter the results of the dir command.

If you are doing it in SAS then you might use a program like this:

```
data want ;
   infile 'dir /b *.sas' pipe truncover ;
   input filename $200. ;
   if lowcase(scan(filename,-1,'.'))='sas' ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's an interesting approach when I am in SAS itself. For the other times I will try using powershell.